# How do I get Picasa showing MP4 videos?

Tags: windows-10, mp4, codec, picasa, video-codecs

My research suggests that in order to get MP4s visible in Picasa (on Windows 10) I need to either install QuickTime or a codec pack.

> *[Edit 16 Jan 2020] To save you trying, it turns out that this is false as neither QuickTime or a codec pack will enable videos in Picasa.*

Both options aren't particularly appealing (for [security](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA16-105A) and [stability](https://lifehacker.com/5877208/what-are-codec-packs-and-should-i-use-them) reasons).

**Is there another way to get MP4 videos displayed in Picasa?**

(Changing photo software isn't an option)

Comment: I wonder how long you can use a discontinued and unsupported image software, before changing IS an option. Seems like security and stability really isn’t that important to you. :)

Comment: @Appleoddity You try having that conversation with my mother! 

Answer (score 2):

---

For anyone else that stumbles into this thread, searching for why Picasa won't import mp4 video files, for me the simple fix was using CodecTweak.

https://codecguide.com/download_other.htm#codectweaktool

I changed the Preferred DirectShow 32bit filters for H.264 and mp4 types to use the Merit setting.  THAT'S ALL.  Nothing else.  No other codec packs loaded, nothing.

1. download CodecTweak
2. quit Picasa
3. use CodecTweak to make the DirectShow changes and quit
4. start Picasa again
5. go to Tools->Options and de-select the Movies checkbox.
6. quit Picasa
7. restart Picasa go to Tools->Options and select the Movies checkbox.

This lead to Picasa then scanning the folders automatically and adding in all the videos it found.

The quitting/restarting deselecting/selecting steps seem to be important in getting Picasa to "reset itself" for handling the video files.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's deprecated and knowing it's Picasa Photo Viewer. That said, MP4 should show up and show the thumbnail. However, it could depend on the codec of the MP4, maybe that's why it doesn't see them? Perhaps your system is missing codecs. You could always install the latest K-Lite Codec Package from [K-lite](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

As a test Picasa 3.9 displays a few test MP4 files without issue. They are both encoded as

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
```

I also would suggest as others have, probably move away from Picasa for your own sanity and for your future in general. I do understand tho, Picasa at the time was a great desktop app for photo management.

Answer (score 0):

(Warning: Picasa showed the popups indicating it was detecting the converted files, but is not showing them...)
For the one other person on the planet who still wants to do this, here's a system I worked out that I'm happy with: using ffmpeg to convert the mp4 to wmv.

I downloaded ffmpeg from here: https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/

For each file I want to convert I first do

```
ffprobe "[filepath]"
```

(ffprobe comes with ffmpeg)

Part of the output from this indicates what kind of video stream is in the mp4:

```
 Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661) ...
```

If it is already wmv2 (it happened in some cases for me), the conversion is simple:

```
ffmpeg -i "[filepath]" -c:v copy -c:a copy "[targetpath]"
```

(`targetpath` needs to end with wmv)

In other cases, you need to notice the bitrate (e.g. `18981 kb/s`), and inject it into the conversion command like so:

```
ffmpeg -i "[filepath]" -c:v wmv2 -b:v 18981k -c:a copy "[targetpath]"
```